# Unable to upload blob(video) to azure blob storage

Tags: android, azure, android-studio, blobstorage

Hello everyone i am trying to upload the captured video from the camera of an android device to azure blob storage but i am unable to do it here is my code.

```
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =   CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("clipshotitems");

      final String filepath=       Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/video.mp4";
        // Create the container if it does not exist.
     //   container.createIfNotExists();
       BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions=new BlobContainerPermissions();
        containerPermissions.setPublicAccess(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.CONTAINER);
        container.uploadPermissions(containerPermissions);
       CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("miniclipId");


        FileInputStream file= new FileInputStream(filepath);
        blob.upload(file,source.length());
        p1.hide();
      `
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: @GauravMantri sir there is no error but the video is not uploading to my container on the azure portal :(